# Unrecoverable Error for HystrixCommand so will throw HystrixRuntimeException and not apply fallback

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud gateway and trying to use the circuit breaker. In the gateway I have added a fallback(failover-service) method for the service(cricketer-service) in the gateway(cricketer-gateway).
The failover service works fine individually. Failover service is named as *cricketer-failover-service* in application.properties.

Gateway config

```
@Configuration
public class RoutesConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/cricketers*")
                        .filters(f -> f.circuitBreaker(c -> c.setName("cricketerFb")
                            .setFallbackUri("forward:/cricketer-failover")
                                .setRouteId("cricketer-failover")
                        ))
                        .uri("lb://cricketer-service")
                        .id("cricketer-service"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/cricketer-failover*")
                        .uri("lb://cricketer-failover-service")
                        .id("cricketer-failover-service"))
                .build();
    }
```

When I turn the service off and then hit the endpoint, I receive an exception

2020-08-30 14:17:28.670 ERROR 14766 --- [or-http-epoll-3] com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand      : Unrecoverable Error for HystrixCommand so will throw HystrixRuntimeException and not apply fallback.

```
java.lang.Exception: Throwable caught while executing.
        at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.getExceptionFromThrowable(AbstractCommand.java:1976) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar:1.5.18]
```

Stacktrace - https://gist.github.com/nirmalks/4adb8b64955625df6b5a22469f106bfe
Code - https://github.com/nirmalks/cricketer-microservice/tree/hystrix-fallback-err

Comment: Were you able to fix it @Nirmal ?

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh No, I have not. And I have not worked in this since so I'm not sure if the code is relevant anymore.